# Alternative to Dlookup but saving values in table

Tags: ms-access

Ive got 2 fields in a form both row sourced to a previous table.

I want field 2 to automatically according to the choice that field one was chosen.

The only I managed to do this was via dlookup which worked but didnt save the value to the forms table.

How would I do this?

It would be simple and Im overlooking it Im sure..

Comment: I am sorry you are going to have to explain this more clearly. You want field 2 to automatically what?

Comment: As far as I understand it: Table with (at least) two fields, where one field depends on the other. I choose a value in field 1, field 2 automatically gets a value corresponding to the value in field 1. Problem is the value won't be saved. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the control source of a bound control*, so if you want to bind the control to a field in your table so that it updates, you have to use code, so in the `After Update` event of the combobox, add some code to update the two controls. You can use DLookUp, a column in the combo, or a recordset.

```
Private Sub Combo7_AfterUpdate()
    ''DlookUp
    Me.Text1 = DLookup("Id", "Table1", "AText='" & Me.sometext & "'")

    ''A column in the combo, note that numbering starts from zero
    Me.Text1 = Me.Combo7.Column(1)
    
    ''A recordset
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    ssql = "SELECT Id FROM Table1 WHERE AText ='" & Me.sometext & "'"
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(ssql)
    Me.Text1 = rs!Id
End Sub
```

---

* Forms have controls, tables have fields or columns.